# VR without Gyro

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Is there any app similar to Google Cardboard that can work without Gyroscope sensor. And by work I mean:

1. Play simple movies that doesn't require head movement
2. And if possible, can simulate gyroscope with help of accelerometer and compass. It can be done.  Here is a open source development going on about  [Virtual Gyro](https://github.com/memsindustrygroup/Open-Source-Sensor-Fusion/wiki/Virtual%20Gyro)

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear whether you're asking for advice on finding a ready to install software or making it yourself.

Comment: ready to install software

Comment: SO is about solving bugs. For software recommendations, try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=vr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some VR games on Android work fine without gyro :
try

Space X Hunter VR : 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.creation3d.spacexhuntervr

VR Bowl :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.creation3d.vrbowl

and the games from Fibrum

Answer (score 1):

you can create a virtual gyro but you will require root, xposed and an xposed module. You can google it for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The games I found without Google cardboard was western vr,ghost hunt,dead zombie shootout vr,dead zombie survival vr,and house of terror vr free most games are demo's when you get to end of the demo it will stop all the ones I mentioned you don't need a controller it moves on its own my boys played them they are both gamer's and they gave me a thumbs up I know I am going to buy house of terror and ghosthunters so far I like them more love these games I will let you know if I find more